# Change TimeStamp display in terminal

Tags: coreutils

When I do a `ls -al` the timestamp display is Month date time - would like it to be yy/mm/dd or just know WHERE to modify this?

I also cannot edit dconf-editor.  - that shows %l:%M %p when I try to change it it just reverts back. I used sudo to launch.

Desktop shows time only

Nautilus shows weekday day month year time.

Answer (score 1):

In the end of your `~/.bashrc`, paste the code below:

```
RAW_CUR_LS_ALIAS=`alias ls || echo "ls"`
CUR_LS_ALIAS=`echo "$RAW_CUR_LS_ALIAS" | sed "s/^alias ls='\|'$//g"`
alias ls="$CUR_LS_ALIAS --time-style='+%y/%m/%d %T'"
```

After pasting this command, save and close the file.

And run

`source ~/.bashrc`

Now try:

`ls -al`

You'll need `source` only this time, when you restart all of your gnome-terminal windows, it will always load the alias automatically.

---

If you want to customize it by yourself just take a look at the [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/date.1.html) of date and look for FORMAT options.

Comment: Be careful about overriding the existing `ls` alias defined in the default `.bashrc`. If you just append this new declaration you'll lose the prior's text coloring.

Comment: Updated the answer to keep settings found in previous defined alias for ls